# What is the meaning of "A rolling reduce on a keyed data stream ?" DataStream reduce function

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to understand the A "rolling" reduce on a keyed data stream.

I have a scenario, where I want to neglect some messages which arrive in certain time. E.g. First Event-> in between events -> the last Event, I just want to capture first and the last event and want to skip/remove in between events from the stream. And importantly, it should be happen on the basis of some key.. In my case its not happing when I am applying key.

Answer (score 1):

A rolling reduce is probably not what you are looking for. It holds an element as state. Whenever a new element is received, it applies a `ReduceFunction` on the stored and a new element. The result of the function is emitted and updates the state. This operator has no concept of an end element and will always have state and wait for the next element to process.

I think a stateful `FlatMapFunction` or `ProcessFunction` would be the right approach for your use case. The function would store the start element as state and wait for the end element to arrive. Once it is received, you emit the start and the end element and clean up the state.

The overall program could look like this:

```
val stream[Event] = ...
val startEnd[(Event, Event)] = stream
  .keyBy(yourKey)
  .flatMap(yourStatefulFunction)
```

Comment: there is no direct distinguish between first and last event, I need to calculate it using time laps in between (and time is dynamic factor) some messages with key x having t time and some message with key Y having t2 time delay.

As you suggested, I am looking @ https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/stream/process_function.html